# What my host could be blocking| dynamic scripts doesnt load

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamic-loading

I am not an expert in javascripts/ajax, but I know some html,css an php....

And I have a joomla blogs... with ajax extensions...

The problem is, that some scripts are supposed to do dynamical loading, and they never work on my current host...but they are loading just fine on my other hosting, on wamp, etc....I don't know what is going on and I believe the host is something blocking, but their only answer is "contact developer, we can't find anything"....:(
I believe they are still blocked something, but I can't tell what....I don't get even error messages, and firebug doesn't show any errors, just not loading and that's it....

The first case was with search results, which were supposed to load more, when scrolling down --> I got a blank page, and no errors, even I set error displaying to the max...

Second case - now - I have on home page intro from articles, that are loading fine, but when I set in a module the option - "to load more on click of button" - nothing happens...

but on both cases it works fine on wamp and another similar hosting....

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already I would try to put the URL that your AJAX is using right into your browser and see what that returns.